# Unity freeze after press play button with Firebase 6.15.0

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I do not know what I'm doing wrong, but Unity freezes a few seconds after clicking the Play Button. First, there is a load on the processor, and then it disappears.

Reinstalled Unity several times, as well as the Firebase SDK.

If you disable the script that interacts with Firebase, then unity works fine.

I'm using the Firebase Analytics and Firebase Database.

Code:

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine.Assertions.Must;

public class Leaderboard : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public DataScript data = new DataScript();

    DatabaseReference reference;

    public GameObject unavailable;
    public GameObject available;
    public Text code;

    public List<Player> player;

    public Transform content;
    public GameObject prefab;
    LeaderPrefab lf;
    public List<GameObject> pr;

    int i = 0;

    public InputField iF;

    public GameObject changePan;

    public Text Nickname;
    public Text Id;
    public Text Score;


    void Start()
    {
        //data = FindObjectOfType<DataScript>();

        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Debug.Log("Server is available");

                available.SetActive(true);
                unavailable.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                available.SetActive(false);
                unavailable.SetActive(true);
                code.text = "Server has some errors. Try again later";

            }
        });

        #region Server Instance and Server Status
        Debug.Log("StartCheck");
        FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://troubles-detex.firebaseio.com/");
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

        if (reference.Child("Server Status") == null)
        {
            reference.Child("Server Status").Child("Available").SetValueAsync("true");
        }

        string returnedCode = reference.Child("Server Status").Child("Available").GetValueAsync().ToString();

        if (returnedCode == "false")
        {
            available.SetActive(false);
            unavailable.SetActive(true);
            code.text = "Server is temporarily unavailable.";
            Debug.Log("Server is temporarily unavailable.");
            return;
        }
        if (returnedCode == "maintenance")
        {
            available.SetActive(false);
            unavailable.SetActive(true);
            code.text = "Server under maintenance. Try again later.";
            Debug.Log("Server under maintenance. Try again later.");
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Checked");
        #endregionenter image description here

        reference.Child("User").ValueChanged += 
        (object sender2, ValueChangedEventArgs e2) =>
        {
            #region if database is broken
            if (e2.DatabaseError != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError(e2.DatabaseError.Message);
                return;
            }
            #endregion
            Debug.Log("Lets go");
            if (e2.Snapshot != null && e2.Snapshot.ChildrenCount > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("all is good");

                #region Clear old
                player.Clear();
                pr = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("leader").ToList();
                foreach(GameObject p in pr)
                {
                    Destroy(p);
                }
                #endregion

                #region Display leaders
                foreach (DataSnapshot childSnapshot in e2.Snapshot.Children)
                {

                    var name1 = childSnapshot.Child("Nickname").Value.ToString();
                    var id1 = childSnapshot.Child("Id").Value.ToString();
                    var score1 = childSnapshot.Child("Score").Value.ToString();

                    player.Add(new Player() { name = name1, id = id1, score = int.Parse(score1) });

                }
                player = player.OrderByDescending(playerR => playerR.score).ToList();
                foreach(Player pl in player)
                {
                    if (i == 50) return;

                    ShowLeaders(pl.name, pl.id, pl.score.ToString());
                    i++;
                }
                #endregion

            }
        };

        #region Show us
        if ((reference.Child("User").Child("nick") + data.ReadString("id")) != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Show us", this);
            Nickname.text = reference.Child("User").Child(data.ReadString("nick") + data.ReadString("id")).Child("Nickname").GetValueAsync().Result.Value.ToString();
            Id.text = reference.Child("User").Child(data.ReadString("nick") + data.ReadString("id")).Child("Id").GetValueAsync().ToString();
            Score.text = reference.Child("User").Child(data.ReadString("nick") + data.ReadString("id")).Child("Score").GetValueAsync().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Register();
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public void ChangeNickname()
    {
        Debug.Log("LAST NAME WAS " + data.ReadString("nick"));
        reference.Child("User").Child(data.ReadString("nick") + data.ReadString("id")).RemoveValueAsync();
        reference.Child("User").Child(iF.text + data.ReadString("id")).Child("Nickname").SetValueAsync(iF.text);
        reference.Child("User").Child(iF.text + data.ReadString("id")).Child("Id").SetValueAsync(data.ReadString("id"));
        reference.Child("User").Child(iF.text + data.ReadString("id")).Child("Score").SetValueAsync(data.ReadString("score"));
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        changePan.SetActive(!changePan.activeInHierarchy);
    }

    public void Register()
    {
        print("Register");
        int i = Random.Range(1, 100000);
        data.Write("id", i);
        reference.Child("User").Child("Player" + i).Child("Nickname").SetValueAsync("Player" + i.ToString());
        reference.Child("User").Child("Player" + i).Child("Id").SetValueAsync(i.ToString());
        reference.Child("User").Child("Player" + i).Child("Score").SetValueAsync("0");
    }

    public void CreateNew()
    {
        if(reference == null)
        {
            FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://troubles-detex.firebaseio.com/");
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
            Debug.Log("Ready");
        }
        int a = Random.Range(1, 100);
        int b = Random.Range(1, 100000);
        int c = Random.Range(1, 1000);
        reference.Child("User").Child("Test" + a).Child("Nickname").SetValueAsync("Test" + a);
        reference.Child("User").Child("Test" + a).Child("Id").SetValueAsync(b.ToString());
        reference.Child("User").Child("Test" + a).Child("Score").SetValueAsync(c.ToString());

    }

    public void ShowLeaders(string nname, string id1, string scorea)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab, content);
        lf = go.GetComponent<LeaderPrefab>();
        lf.nickname.text = nname;
        lf.idT.text = id1;
        lf.scoreT.text = scorea;
    }

}
[System.Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public string name;
    public string id;
    public int score;
}
```

https://prnt.sc/svjlzq
https://prnt.sc/svjo43

Comment: Have you import the plugins separated, or both at the same time? Try to import all firebase packages at the same time to the project and tell me if it works better now please.

Comment: I think the problem was that I first accidentally imported all the 6.14.1 .Net 3.X packages, and then transferred the project to .Net 4.X, and only imported Analytics and Database .Net 4.x. Now I will try to re-import all the packages 6.15.0 .Net 4.X

Comment: @Lotan after importing Crashlytics I have this https://prnt.sc/svpwei

Comment: very strange, but now my laptop is very slow. I don’t know what it is connected with.

Comment: @Lotan can there be a freeze due to the absence of Firebase configuration files?
  ¿Puede haber un congelamiento debido a la ausencia de archivos de configuración de Firebase?

Comment: @Lotan 
No sé qué hacer. Los paquetes se procesan en 4 horas, pero espero que todo vaya más rápido. Escribiré en español para su conveniencia

Comment: Thanks @sinQ ^^ but the language swap is not needed (and absolutly not what StackOverflow admins want) ^^ I've been testing my own Firebase app and I think that the freeze time (which I already have too) is caused by .CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync(), I don't really know if it's possible to avoid, sorry :(

Comment: @Lotan Okay, I'll try to delete these lines(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @Lotan nope, no difference =(

Comment: @Lotan 
I don't think error is here. Through the logs you can see that the last message is "Show us"

Comment: There is currently a known issue regarding Firebase and Unity on Windows: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/639 . Is this new (ie, had you been using 6.14.1 before upgrading to 6.15)? You can try installing iOS support (even on Windows) which will lessen the issue. If that bug looks like it's related, definitely follow along in that thread for updates.

Comment: yep, this issue was **before** 6.15.0, I saw that post and took a script from it. Nothing changed. How can I install iOS support? In my opinion, this branch was closed by words about the 6.15.0 update, which has already been released, but nothing has changed. Moreover, it described a temporary freeze, but I have complete.

Comment: @Lotan https://prnt.sc/sw34jc

Comment: @Lotan I fixed this. My stupid mistake. I turned this 

`foreach(Player pl in player)
                {
                    if (i == 50) return;

                    ShowLeaders(pl.name, pl.id, pl.score.ToString());
                    i++;
                }`
into this:
`foreach(Player pl in player)
                {
                    ShowLeaders(pl.name, pl.id, pl.score.ToString());
                }`
But I think CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync is also broken.
Thank you very much!

Comment: i tried to play with CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync () and Unity freeze

Comment: lmao. My Unity just closed up with no error

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sw3kk0 whaaaaat

Comment: I just saw through the logs that Unity is initializing a package for VR, although I do not make a game for VR helmets. I read several articles saying that the VR package is causing the error `(Filename: C: \ buildslave \ unity \ build \ Runtime / Export / Debug / Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)`

Comment: @Lotan so I think Unity freeze when we are trying to get value in the wrong way. Example, https://troubles-detex.firebaseio.com/User/Player17 - Correct. https://troubles-detex.firebaseio.com/User/Player - Incorrect. I think we are getting the wrong path since my DataScript is not working correctly. Could you please help me find a bug in DataScript?

Comment: the DataScript seems to be fixed. But for some reason, now GetValueAsync () returns not, for example, a nickname, but `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 [Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot]`